# Не могу понять как избавиться от ошибки TypeError: fn.bind is not a function discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Вот есть код:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');

const size = config.colors;
const rainbow = new Array(size);

for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const red = sin_to_hex(i, 0 * Math.PI * 2 / 3); // 0 deg
    const blue = sin_to_hex(i, 1 * Math.PI * 2 / 3); // 120 deg
    const green = sin_to_hex(i, 2 * Math.PI * 2 / 3); // 240 deg

    rainbow[i] = '#' + red + green + blue;
}

function sin_to_hex(i, phase) {
    const sin = Math.sin(Math.PI / size * 2 * i + phase);
    const int = Math.floor(sin * 127) + 128;
    const hex = int.toString(16);

    return hex.length === 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
}

let place = 0;
const servers = config.servers;

function changeColor() {
    for (let index = 0; index < servers.length; ++index) {
        client.guilds.cache.get(servers[index]).roles.cache.find('name', config.roleName).setColor(rainbow[place])
            .catch(console.error);

        if (config.logging) {
            console.log(`[ColorChanger] Changed color to ${rainbow[place]} in server: ${servers[index]}`);
        }
        if (place == (size - 1)) {
            place = 0;
        } else {
            place++;
        }
    }
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.username}!`);
    if (config.speed < 10) {
        console.log("The minimum speed is 60.000, if this gets abused your bot might get IP-banned");
        process.exit(1);
    }
    setInterval(changeColor, config.speed);
});


client.login(config.token);
```

И он выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
    at Map.find (D:\Code\FirstBot\node_modules@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:158:21)
    at Timeout.changeColor [as _onTimeout] (D:\Code\FirstBot\rainbow.js:29:55)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

Я без понятия как это решить, поможете мне пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым параметром [`find`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods) должна быть функция. В примере в вопросе передается строка.

Так как у строки нет метода `bind` и получается указанная ошибка.